# Heroku Rails Force SSL Redirect Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a Rails app that has a staging environment on Heroku as well as a production environment. I want to force ssl on the production environment but not on staging. My application controller (below) shows how I am configured to do so but my staging environment is still trying to force ssl to work and that is causing a redirect loop.

My question is: A) How do I stop the redirect loop and have the application not crash from forcing ssl? and B) What do I have to do to stop force_ssl to not happen in the staging environment that I have not already done?

Thanks!

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  # Make application helpers availble within controllers
  include ApplicationHelper

 # enable_authorization :unless => :devise_controller? # ACl

  before_filter do # ACL work around for attribute mass assignment
    resource = controller_path.singularize.gsub('/', '_').to_sym
    method = "#{resource}_params"
    params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
  end

  rescue_from CanCan::Unauthorized do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  #handling redirection after login basing on the just logged in user role
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    if user.has_role?(:director)
      unless user.organization.nil?
        dashboard_organization_path(user.organization.id) 
      else
        organization_trainings_url
      end
    elsif user.has_role?(:user)
      user_path(user)
    elsif user.has_role?(:admin)
      organization_trainings_url
    else
      root_url
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:first_name, :last_name, :title, :phone, :email,
                                                 :organization_id, :badge, :dl,
                                                 :hire_date, :dl_expiration, :leader_id, :password, :current_password,
                                                 :division_id, :bureau_id]
  end 

  private 

  def ssl_configured?
    Rails.env.production?
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you checked if you `staging` is really `staging`? What does `Rails.env.production?` return in your heroku console?

Comment: false is what i get when i enter that

Comment: And `Rails.env.staging?`?

Comment: Same here. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [Heroku Config Variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) for this.

For example, you could set a config variable named `APP_NAME` with

`heroku config:set APP_NAME=my-app-name`

on each of your Heroku servers, so that you can tell them apart from within your code. You would use this environment/config variable as follows:

```
# in production.rb
config.force_ssl = true unless ENV['APP_NAME'] == 'my-staging-app-name'
```

A better approach though, IMHO, would be to set a variable/flag for what you're trying to do, such as `SKIP_FORCE_SSL.` So, first, you would set the config variable on Heroku with:

`heroku config:set SKIP_FORCE_SSL=true`

Then, in your app, you can then check whether you should force SSL with something like:

`config.force_ssl = true unless ENV['SKIP_FORCE_SSL']`

I'd recommend using the blacklist approach, as above, so that the default is to force SSL if the app can't find the environment variable, or whatever else you're using to check.

If you need to do testing on your development machine while running in production mode (which would use `production.rb`), you can set the same environment variable in your `~/.bash_profile`:

`export SKIP_FORCE_SSL='true'`

(Remember you need to open a new console tab/window for this to take effect. Also note that the environment variable will come back as a string, not a boolean, even if you leave off those quotes.)

Hope this helps!